# How serious is my case and should I get help?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience, neurophysiology

So I have been experimenting a bit with pshycadelics nothing too much , I did lsd twice in a period of 3 months , inbetween i have done mdma once.
Two weeks after my last use of lsd I started noticing something very weird going on in my head ...
As i searched everything about Lsd side effects in a long term I found out that i have got disorganized thinking , it ussualy happens  when Im super exhausted , it ussualy happens in a middle of the night , the weirdest thing about all of this is that i randomly wake up after an hour and half of my sleep and then the disorganized thinking happens ,It lasts for 5 to 10 mins ..smoking a ciggarete helps a lot , at least it helps with my panic , i can not develop a single straight though and somehow i tend to get stuck to one stupid thought n i just loop around it untill the whole thing wears off , after the certain time i forget what the thing i was thinking about was and i can not remember it , how serious this whole thing is and can it get worse , right now i m not that scared when it happens i just live thru it and i even started handling it good , it happened 3 times in two weeks , so its not that often ...

i am definetly done with drugs but should i seek help or shuld i just wait few months and see if it actually is from lsd cuz in that case it should just stop

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE.  I am sorry, but nobody here can properly assess someone's mental health on a site such as this.  If you are having problems, you need to speak to your doctor who can advise you properly and/or send you for further tests or treatment.  I wish you luck.